# What is the format of an RSA public key?

Tags: cryptography, rsa

I have this RSA public key from which I want to get *Modulus* and *exponent* part but not able to get the format in which it is encoded. Can someone please tell how to decode it?

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBBgKBgDI/ranPo8MDfguQfSzqg7mtNlUJLLBK7tlVALyk42agbLTSFcZbs9Yw
t3nSe9yNzZB9ZVrL3O9GXkEb6xvj3dqrog+wWOeFCqNV7BuJNYYC/ef4vlnUFQdw
yswbd7d198qjWBZ7MiZRXxX8qKRln+osTvsDYOMZk93k0cGZgyuJAoGAHkgFohgA
nH93kDPjN4sHaT9WsmZ4ailbMtcnWuLizTRJ2sdGjNrpuwT1R+x1nlYHOeDUSOu6
De0kQJX+HZuQCoha6THsdgcV297krN22FwsDZ1PItXLIr5oC7zcNQaDyAJOIv6BC
ufHQ0IR+L9b9esniMbF8yV0d7EVAaBJiyRk=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: the format is called PEM. You might want to check [RFC1421](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1421.txt) and/or similar.

Comment: see http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18031/the-modulus-of-rsa-public-key

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your key uses PEM encoding, where the type - "PUBLIC KEY" - is indicated in the header and footer lines and the contents are binary encoded using base64 (and the PEM specific line size).

```
$ cat > foo.txt
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBBgKBgDI/ranPo8MDfguQfSzqg7mtNlUJLLBK7tlVALyk42agbLTSFcZbs9Yw
t3nSe9yNzZB9ZVrL3O9GXkEb6xvj3dqrog+wWOeFCqNV7BuJNYYC/ef4vlnUFQdw
yswbd7d198qjWBZ7MiZRXxX8qKRln+osTvsDYOMZk93k0cGZgyuJAoGAHkgFohgA
nH93kDPjN4sHaT9WsmZ4ailbMtcnWuLizTRJ2sdGjNrpuwT1R+x1nlYHOeDUSOu6
De0kQJX+HZuQCoha6THsdgcV297krN22FwsDZ1PItXLIr5oC7zcNQaDyAJOIv6BC
ufHQ0IR+L9b9esniMbF8yV0d7EVAaBJiyRk=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
$ openssl asn1parse -i -in foo.txt 
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 262 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=3 l= 128 prim:  INTEGER           :323FADA9CFA3C3037E0B907D2CEA83B9AD3655092CB04AEED95500BCA4E366A06CB4D215C65BB3D630B779D27BDC8DCD907D655ACBDCEF465E411BEB1BE3DDDAABA20FB058E7850AA355EC1B89358602FDE7F8BE59D4150770CACC1B77B775F7CAA358167B3226515F15FCA8A4659FEA2C4EFB0360E31993DDE4D1C199832B89
  135:d=1  hl=3 l= 128 prim:  INTEGER           :1E4805A218009C7F779033E3378B07693F56B266786A295B32D7275AE2E2CD3449DAC7468CDAE9BB04F547EC759E560739E0D448EBBA0DED244095FE1D9B900A885AE931EC760715DBDEE4ACDDB6170B036753C8B572C8AF9A02EF370D41A0F2009388BFA042B9F1D0D0847E2FD6FD7AC9E231B17CC95D1DEC4540681262C919
```

There you go. I used these commands on a fairly regular Linux system.

Note that your file is weird. A RSA public key consists in two integers, the modulus (*n*) and the public exponent (*e*). It is normally encoded as an ASN.1 structure that is a `SEQUENCE` of two `INTEGER` values. That structure is then supposed to be DER-encoded to form a PKCS#1 encoded public key.

Usually the PKCS#1 defined sequence of bytes becomes part of a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure as value of a `BIT STRING`. This contains also contains an explicit identifier to indicate the key type (i.e. an indication that the key is really of type RSA). In your case, this outer structure is missing, so there is formally no indication, neither in the encoded ASN.1 structure. The ["PUBLIC KEY" type defined in the PEM specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#page-14) however does indicate that this SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure should be present, and that the type of the key should be indicated in the structure.

As a RSA key, it looks a bit strange too. The first integer, purportedly the modulus, has length 1022 bits, which is not very common (developers and cryptographers really love powers of 2, so they won't accept a 1022-bit integer if there is any possibility that they could make a 1024-bit integer). The second integer, the public exponent, is quite large (1021 bits); this is formally supported by RSA, but very rare: public exponents can be very short with no ill effect on security, and this makes public key operations much faster, so there is no real reason for using a large exponent. Some widespread implementations (Windows CryptoAPI...) don't even support public exponents larger than 32 bits.

If what you have is really a RSA public key, then chances are that someone is pulling your leg -- or is doing things in uncommon and probably weak ways. You should change the type in both the header and footer to "RSA PUBLIC KEY" if it is to be treated as a PKCS#1 encoded public key. Preferably this key format should not be used though.

Comment: Indeed `openssl rsa -pubin -noout -text < key` and `openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -noout -text < key` are both unable to parse the ASCII armored text, definitely something unorthodox if it's an RSA public key.

Comment: now I had n p q e of this public key, but the given encrypted message is a .bin file now I am not getting a way to decrypt the data from bin file using these values.

Comment: @puzzlepalace since this is actually PKCS#1, if you fix the header&trailer to `RSA PUBLIC KEY` then `-RSAPublicKey_in` works. (The values remain suspicious, as Thomas describes.)