# How to encode a public key in PKCS#8?

Tags: research, standards, pkcs8

[RFC5958](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5958) defines a set of enhancements to the [PKCS#8 key serialization format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5208), bumping the `version` field up to `1` and additionally permitting serialization of public keys for arbitrary asymmetric cryptographic algorithms.

```
OneAsymmetricKey ::= SEQUENCE {
  version                   Version,
  privateKeyAlgorithm       PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier,
  privateKey                PrivateKey,
  attributes            [0] Attributes OPTIONAL,
  ...,
  [[2: publicKey        [1] PublicKey OPTIONAL ]],
  ...
}

PrivateKeyInfo ::= OneAsymmetricKey -- Overwriting the definition in RFC5208 which only supports private keys
```

However, I'm unclear on the following:

- What belongs in the **third field** of the `OneAsymmetricKey` sequence when one is encoding *only* a public key?

---

I'm writing an implementation of some current research/experimental cryptographic algorithms, and I'm currently trying to write the serialization and deserialization capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand RFC 5958.

> `OneAsymmetricKey` … when one is encoding only a public key?

PKCS#8 remains a **private key** serialization format. Just because the `v2` update lets you *bundle* a public key alongside the private key for convenience, does *not* mean it's become a public key serialization format. You **can't use `OneAsymmetricKey`** to encode *only* a public key.

What you should be producing, instead, when you only intend to serialize a public key, is merely and exactly a **`SubjectPublicKeyInfo` object** as defined in [IETF RFC 5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280) (with, of course, any needed [ASCII armoring](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7468) added on top):

```
AlgorithmIdentifier  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     algorithm               OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
     parameters              ANY DEFINED BY algorithm OPTIONAL  }

SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     algorithm            AlgorithmIdentifier,
     subjectPublicKey     BIT STRING -- DEFINED BY algorithm --  }
```

This is how all other standardized **public** cryptographic keys are serialized for transfer in X.509-adjacent contexts. Everything from [Ed25519/X25519 and Ed448/X448](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8410.html#section-10.1) to [NIST ECC](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/v3.10.1/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/ECC.py#L659-L660) curves uses this SPKI format. (RSA public keys' [legacy PKCS#1 encoding](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/115869/26186) is *the* exception to this, and even those keys [may be reserialized into SPKI format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18995687/1874170).)

Comment: PKIX publickey encodings for other algorithms are in 3279 (referenced by 3280/5280) plus 4055 4491 5480 5756. (5758 and 8692 add signatures but not keys.) The PKCS1-labelled-PUBLIC-KEY file in #115862 is NOT standard, as both the bear and I explained, and 7468 (as you linked) specifies.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Indeed, that `BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY` encoding is more of a _de facto_ "standard" if anything… certainly not to be imitated for future software implementations